# Angular object is null on constructor even if it is initialized in router event

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have the following code that I initialize through a router event or from constructor.

```
export class Component2 implements OnInit {
    constructor() {
      if (this.initialFormValues === undefined)
          this.initialFormValues = new MyFormFilters();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    this.router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: any) => e instanceof RoutesRecognized),
      pairwise())
      .subscribe((e: any) => {
        if (e && e[0] && e[0].url === "/app/module1/myRoute1") {
          if (this.initialFormValues === undefined)
            this.initialFormValues = new MyFormFilters();

          this.initialFormValues.dateFrom = moment(this.reportsStateService.dateFrom);
          this.initialFormValues.dateTo = this.reportsStateService.dateTo;
        }
      });
    }
}
```

When I am in `myRoute1` and click browser button I can see that the code event subscription is fired and the `initialFormValues` object is initialized and assigned without any issues. It then gets into constructor and `this.initialFormValues` is undefined. Why is that happening if router event subscription initialized the object successfully?

Comment: Why are you saying, constructor fire after the ngOnInit ? code in constructor is executed before ngOnInit.

Comment: `ngOnInit` is always gonna fire after the constructor has been called. So there must be some timing issue here why you're getting results from the subscriptions before the constructor is called, maybe the constructor is being called twice ?

Comment: @pantonis not sure this is the sequence calls. First the component's constructor is called and then the Oninit life cycle hook. Just to make you understand, put console.log in each and log method carrying different parameter to check which method is called.

Comment: I think I found the problem but I dont know how to solve it. Each time the component loads it creates a new subscription. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your description of what happens isn't possible. 
The constructor is called first, and then, a method (`ngOnInit()`) of the constructed object can be called.

If you see the reverse order, it simply means you're observing two different Component2 objects.

The first one's router event handler is called, and later, the second one is being constructed. But of course, two objects don't share their instance fields. So even though the first one already has an initialied `initialFormValues` field, the other one doesn't.